# Why does my Xcode 8 GM have 50+ Simulator versions to choose from?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

How can I fix this? I have 2.5 full pages of this: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into Window -> Devices. Then just select the Simulators you don't want and delete them (by hitting the Delete key, or right-clicking).

You can also un-select the "Show in Run Destinations Menu" item (when you right-click).

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in one of the earlier betas which could have caused extra devices to get created.  The easiest thing to do is get back to a vanilla state.  Quite Xcode.app, Simulator.app, etc and then run:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService 
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
```